# How to determine a repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, repository

I am trying to install ruby-mp3info.
I have the following URL from which I can access the gem in my browser:
http://bitbucket.org/moumar/ruby-mp3info/src/
I would like to specify this source while running `gem install ruby-mp3info`
When I run `gem install ruby-mp3info --source=http://bitbucket.org/moumar/ruby-mp3info/src`, though, I get a message back claiming this is not a repository. How do I find repositories?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gem repositories must follow some special requirements. An URI is not necessary a repository.
Actually, there are only a few public repositories such as:

- RubyGems (which now powers also GemCutter.org and RubyForge.org legacy indexes, see qrush's comment)
- GitHub (no longer active on new gems)

If you want to install `ruby-mp3info`, just enter

```
$ gem install ruby-mp3info
```

The Gem is already hosted on the standard Gem repository (Gemcutter/RubyGems).

```
$ gem search ruby-mp3info -r

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

ruby-mp3info (0.6.13)
```

If for whatever reason you need the latest build, then install it from source.
Download the code, enter the project root and type

```
$ ruby install.rb config
$ ruby install.rb setup
$ ruby install.rb install
```

Comment: RubyGems.org == gems.rubyforge.org == gemcutter.org. I wish StackOverflow allowed for editing.

http://update.gemcutter.org/2010/02/20/rubygems-org-move-complete.html